# Crud Repository, date comparison

Tags: java, date, spring-boot

I have the following sql query:

```
select * from wash_history w where w.wash_id in
  (select wash.id from wash where wash.car_wash_id = 17)
and w.time between '2017-07-13' and  '2017-07-22'
```

And I want to create this query inside interface that extends `CrudRepository`. The method is

```
Page<WashHistory> findWashHistoryByTimeBetweenOrderByTimeDesc(Date dateFrom,
                                                              Date dateTo,
                                                              Pageable pageable);
```

But this method always returns an empty list, I think is it due to Java date and SQL TimeStamp? If you want some more details I can add them to question.  My class:

```
public class WashHistory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Column(name = "wash_price")
    private Double washPrice;
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "car_wash_name")
    private String carWashName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "time")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date time;
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
    @Column(name = "bonuses")
    private Integer bonuses=0;
    @JoinColumn(name = "wash_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Wash washId;}
```

ANd wash class

```
 public class Wash implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
    @Column(name = "using_bonuses")
    private Boolean usingBonuses=false;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_status_time")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastStatusTime;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "washId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<WashHistory> washHistorySet;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "washId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private WashComment washCommentSet;
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_wash_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private CarWash carWashId;}
```

My pageble

```
public class LimitAndOffsetPageable extends PageRequest {
        private int page;
        private int size;
        public LimitAndOffsetPageable(int page, int size){
            super(page,size);
            this.page=page;
            this.size=size;
        }
        @Override
        public int getOffset(){
            return this.page;
        }
}
```

I pass to `findWashHistoryByTimeBetweenOrderByTimeDesc(new LimitAndOffsetPageable (0,100))`  (offset = 0 , limit = 100)

Comment: Show us your entity class.

Comment: Thank for response, i add wash and wash history

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by using bad naming conventions: Your entities should look like following: (removed redundant lines - if you want to add constraints like not null, add them in `@Column`)

```
@Entity
public class WashHistory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "wash_price")
    private Double washPrice;
    @Column(name = "car_wash_name")
    private String carWashName;
    @Column(name = "time")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date time;
    private String status;
    private Integer bonuses=0;
    @JoinColumn(name = "wash_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Wash wash;
}
```

Now, the method could be:

```
Page<WashHistory> findAllByWashIdIdAndTimeBetween(Integer id, Date start, Date end, Pageable pageable)
```

Sort property should be put into `pageable` object.

Comment: No, my naming convention working fine , but when i add date to my method it begin to return an empty list

Comment: @АлмасАбдразак try the method I suggested. It's correct. You could show us what is your pageable.

Comment: Thank you ,but Your method is findAllByTimeBetween, but i want to select only wash_histories with specific wash_id that's between two dates

Comment: @АлмасАбдразак updated - your field name washId causes need to double Id in the method.